# Как взять title, process, process id активного окна?

Tags: c++, winapi

Хочу в этом switch, отловить  title, process, process id. У меня есть 2 функции

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    //while(is_working_)
    if (nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    switch (nCode)
    {
    case  HCBT_ACTIVATE:
        break;
    case HCBT_CREATEWND: 
        break;
    case HCBT_DESTROYWND:
        break;
    case HCBT_MINMAX:
        break;
    case HCBT_MOVESIZE:
        break;
    case HCBT_SETFOCUS:
        break;
    case HCBT_SYSCOMMAND:
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Первая, ловит тайтл окна.

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    hwnd = GetForegroundWindow(); //get handle of currently active window
    if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd)) // check whether window is visible
    {
        char wnd_title[256];
        GetWindowText(hwnd, wnd_title, sizeof(wnd_title));
        std::cout << wnd_title << std::endl;
    }
    return true; // function must return true if you want to continue enumeration
}
```

Вторая, процес айди и процес нейм:

```
void PrintProcessNameAndID(DWORD processID)
{
    TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

    // Get a handle to the process.

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
        PROCESS_VM_READ,
        FALSE, processID);

    // Get the process name.

    if (NULL != hProcess)
    {
        HMODULE hMod;
        DWORD cbNeeded;

        if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod),
            &cbNeeded))
        {
            GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
                sizeof(szProcessName) / sizeof(TCHAR));
        }
    }

    // Print the process name and identifier.

    _tprintf(TEXT("%s  (PID: %u)\n"), szProcessName, processID);

    // Release the handle to the process.

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
}
```

Возможно ли это сделать одной функцией?

Comment: Нельзя. Разве что такую функцию вы напишите сами.

Comment: Кстати hProcess вам не обязательно знать.

Comment: а как по другому сделать? можете привести примеры?

Answer (score 1):

У вас всё правильно, осталось только положить под одно из условий в свитче, вот так:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (nCode)
    {
    case  HCBT_ACTIVATE:
        break;

    case HCBT_CREATEWND: 
        break;

    case HCBT_DESTROYWND:

    //При вызове по HCBT_DESRTOYWND
    //wParam является хэндлом на уничтожаемое окно
        if ( IsWindowVisible( (HWND)wParam ) )
        {
            char wnd_title[256];
            GetWindowText((HWND)wParam, wnd_title, sizeof(wnd_title));
            std::cout << wnd_title << std::endl;

            //Получаем PID
            DWORD pid;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId( (HWND)wParam, &pid );

            //Получаем handle
            HANDLE hProcess;
            hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                PROCESS_VM_READ,
                FALSE, pid);

            //Получаем имя процесса         
            TCHAR szProcessName[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("<unknown>");

            if ( hProcess )
            {
                HMODULE hMod;
                DWORD cbNeeded;

                if (EnumProcessModules(hProcess, &hMod, sizeof(hMod),
                    &cbNeeded))
                {
                    GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szProcessName,
                        sizeof(szProcessName) / sizeof(TCHAR));
                }
            }

            CloseHandle(hProcess);
        }

        break;

    case HCBT_MINMAX:
        break;

    case HCBT_MOVESIZE:
        break;

    case HCBT_SETFOCUS:
        break;

    case HCBT_SYSCOMMAND:
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: 8 месяцев прошло, но мб поможет кому